# TypeError: schema should be StructType or list or None

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Can someone explain to me what's happening in my code? Below I provide a small reproducible snippet. When I execute `df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, mh.get_schema)`, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: schema should be StructType or list or None, but got:
<bound method MyHandler.get_schema of <my_handler.MyHandler instance
at 0x7f2f359890e0>>
```

But why??? The schema is defined in `__init__(self)` of `MyHandler`.

```
class MyHandler:

    def __init__(self):

        self.alarm_schema = StructType(
            [
                StructField('alarm_id', StringType()),
                StructField('timestamp',LongType())
            ])

    def get_schema(self):
        return self.alarm_schema


def main(argv):

    spark = SparkSession \
                 .builder \
                 .appName("Test") \
                 .master("local[2]") \
                 .getOrCreate()

    mh = MyHandler()

    rows = [
            (
                "12",
                1536585248000
            )
    ]

    df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, mh.get_schema) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: What's wrong with my question? It's clear and reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either call the method:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, mh.get_schema())
```

or make it a property

```
@property
def get_schema(self):
    return self.alarm_schema
```